# How can I prove that the sum $4^n+n^4$ is a composite number for all $n>1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $4^n+n^4$ is always a composite number? For all $n>1$ and $n$ is an integer.

Comment: See https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090202070229AADg3kj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the question in two cases:

$1$.If $n$ is even, $n^4+4^n$ is divisible by $4$ and hence it is composite.

$2$.If n is odd, suppose $n=2p+1$, where $p$ is positive integer.

Then  $n^4+4^n$ = $n^4+4*4^{2p}$= ${n^4+4(2^p)^4}$ which is of the form $n^4+4b^4 $ where $b$ is positive integer ($=2^p$).

$n^4+4b^4 =(n^4+4b^2+4b^4)-4b^2=(n^2+2b+2b^2)(n^2-2b+2b^2)$ .

Now  $(n^2-2b+2b^2)$ can not be equal to $1$ because $n>1$ and $2b(b-1)>1$ {since $b=2^p$}.

Also by the same reason $(n^2+2b+2b^2)$ can't be equal to $1$. So we get that $(n^2+2b+2b^2)(n^2-2b+2b^2)$ is not same as $(n^4+4b^4)(1)$  and hence we find that $n^4+4b^4$ is composite number consequently $n^4+4^n$ is composite number when $n$ is odd.

Hence, $n^4+4^n$ is composite for $n>1$. We are done.

Comment: "If $4$ is even": I assume you mean "If $n$ is even"?

Comment: Yes, @BrianTung, I shall edit it. Thanks.

Comment: You should mention that both those factors $n^2+2b+2b^2$ and $n^2-2b+2b^2$ are always greater than $1$.

Comment: @TonyK,  have edited it

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Use *Sophie Germain*'s identity:
$$x^4+4y^4=(x^2-2xy+2y^2)(x^2+2xy+2y^2).$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

There are two cases to consider, $n$ even and $n$ odd.
Clearly 2 divides $n^4+4^n$ for $n$ even. For the odd case:
$$n^4 + 4^{2m+1}= (n^2)^2 + (2^{2m+1})^2
  = (n^2 + 2^{2m+1})^2 − 2^{2m+2}n^2
  = (n^2 + 2^{2m+1} + 2^{m+1}n)(n^2 + 2^{2m+1} − 2^{m+1}n)$$